# Data structure pointer handling in C

Tags: c, memory-management, struct, linked-list

I have a struct like this;

```
struct abc
{
    char bbb[10];
    char ccc[4];
    char ddd[6];
    int i1;
    int i2;
    struct abc *prior, *next;
};
struct abb *start, *last, *this, *temp;
```

I have a lot of code using these pointers start,last, etc. so I would like to use them but I would like to add pointers to the struct and pointers within the struct to accomplish the following:
load the struct up with data then depending on the value of i1 for example, display and change data when the value of i1 = 0 or when the value of i1 = 1 or the contents of the struct regardless of the value of i1. And, at the end of the day save the whole struct to file with changes made in any of the three conditions.
I thought to have added pointers such as these:

```
    struct abc *prior1, *next1;
    struct abc *prior2, *next2;
};
struct abb *start1, *last1...etc.
struct abb *start2, *last2...etc.
```

I can have:

```
start = start1;
last  = last1;
```

But how then do I reference

```
prior1
next1
```

Or tell me a better way of doing this.

Comment: Sorry, I've read it three times, but I don't understand your problem.

Comment: Matthias, I believe I put my response to you in the wrong place. Here it is again. What I have is a struct with a set of data. I want to add a second set of data with the same data members. I want to be able to see both sets of data and edit both sets of data on a single display or just see and edit one of the set at a time. Then save the structure with both sets to file.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking for advice on a serialization strategy.  I'd suggest writing free **operator<< and operator>>** methods for handling I/O on your struct, where the pointers are referenced in a **map** that assigns an ascending **numeric ID** value to each.  When writing, upon visiting each struct pointer, you check the map, and if the ID is found, you simply write out the ID and nothing else.  Otherwise, you add the next available ID to the map, assign the ID to the pointer, and then write out the entire struct.  When reading, you reverse the process, reading in each ID and looking in the map for that pointer.  If it's not found, you have the first instance, so you proceed to read in the entire struct and store it in the map.  Otherwise, you retrieve the previously read struct from the map and assign the pointer.  This general strategy is used by **CArchive** serialization (Microsoft Foundation Classes).  There may be some open source libraries to do the same.

Comment: Matthias, What I have is a struct with a set of data.  I want to add a second set of data with the same data members. I want to be able to see both sets of data and edit both sets of data on a single display or just see and edit one of the set at a time. Then save the structure with both sets to file.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear.

You might just need to check out C pointers, and such syntax as `start->prior` which references the value of `prior` contained within `start`.

E.g.

```
// Set the i1 value of start to 42

start->i1 = 42;

printf("The answer is: %d\n", start->i2);
```

Or you might want to have the equivalent of *methods* to interact with one of your structures.

For example:

```
struct abc
{
    char bbb[10];
    char ccc[4];
    char ddd[6];
    int i1;
    int i2;
    struct abc *prior, *next;
};

struct abb *start, *last, *this, *temp;

/**
 * Set the BBB of struct target to a given value.
 * @param   value     the value to set
 * @return            pointer to the target
 */
struct abc *setBBB(struct abc *target, char *value)
{
    strncpy(target->bbb, value, sizeof(target->bbb));
    return target;
}

char *getBBB(struct abc *target)
{
    return target->bbb;
}

struct abc *next(struct abc *target)
{
    return target->next;
}

int getI1(struct abc *target)
{
    return target->i1;
}
```

> to accomplish the following: load the struct up with data then
>   depending on the value of i1 for example, display and change data when
>   the value of i1 = 0 or when the value of i1 = 1 or the contents of the
>   struct regardless of the value of i1.

This you would do with:

```
switch(getI1(start))
{
    case 0:
        setBBB(start, "Hello"); // NOTE: to treat this as a string,
                                // at most 9 characters are allowed,
                                // else the terminating zero will be lost.
        break;
    case 1:
        setBBB(start, "World"); // ditto.
        break;
    ...
}
```

> And, at the end of the day save the whole struct to file with changes made in any of the three conditions.

You want to save the structure to a file, you need something like

```
int saveStruct(char *filename, int position, struct abc *target)
{
    int ret;
    FILE *fp;
    if (NULL == (fp = fopen(filename, "r+")))
    {
        if (NULL == (fp = fopen(filename, "w")))
        {
            return -1; // Error.
        }
    }
    fseek(fp, position * sizeof(struct abc), SEEK_SET);
    ret = fwrite(target,  sizeof(struct abc), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return ret;
}
```

The above has some problems, though. The values of pointers (*prior and *next) will become meaningless once saved to disk, and will remain so when loaded from disk. So the `loadStruct()` function will require as additional parameters the values of *prior and *next to be restored.

Also, you can't (but it depends on the platform) save a structure at position #1 if you haven't saved one at position #0 before. And each save performs an expensive open-and-close.

```
int loadStruct(char *filename, int position, struct abc *target)
{
    int ret;
    FILE *fp;
    if (NULL == (fp = fopen(filename, "r")))
    {
        return -1; // Error.
    }
    fseek(fp, position * sizeof(struct abc), SEEK_SET);
    ret = fread(target,  sizeof(struct abc), 1, fp);

    target->prior = NULL;
    target->next  = NULL;

    fclose(fp);
    return ret;
}
```

// The above, tested with the test case below, returns 'Hello!' as expected.

```
int main()
{
    struct abc *start, *another;
    start   = malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
    setBBB(start, "Hello!");
    saveStruct("file.bin", 0, start);

    another = malloc(sizeof(struct abc));
    loadStruct("file.bin", 0, another);

    printf("Re-read: %s.\n", getBBB(another));
}
```